# Merging several DEMs into one using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dem, merge

Is there any ArcGIS 10 tool to merge several DEM into a single one?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69405/how-can-to-merge-dems-in-arcgis-for-desktop-10-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure

Merging DEMs

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//010300000068000000.htm

Comment: I can't find the "Production Contouring" in the "Toolbars" menu (spatial analyst and 3d analyst are activated)...

Comment: Ok you don't have ESRI Production Mapping extension - try DEM Mosaic http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t000000p4000000.htm

Comment: Thaks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 6):

In ArcGIS 10, this can be done on-the-fly.

One of the new features being to create a [Mosaic Dataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000037000000.htm).
There is also the [Image Analysis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_the_Image_Analysis_window/009t000001tm000000/) window that will allow you to apply filters, do processing, analysis, also on-the-fly.

These two tools can save you tonnes of processing time and disk space, as data will not be duplicated.