# Merging DEMs in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-10.2, merge

I'm trying to merge some DEMs downloaded from USGS. When I used ArcGIS 9.2 there was an expression to be used in raster calculator to do that. I used it again but, unfortunately, it doesn't work in ArcGIS 10.2.

What can I do?

I do not have the *Production Contouring* toolbar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Start by converting them to raster formats (assuming they are in DEM format to start with): 
[image]

then use the 'Mosaic to New Raster' tool to combine the different rasters into a single one:
[image]

Make sure that they are in the same units before mosaicing them or they will look really odd when you stitch them together.

That's the basic approach I use, I'm assuming the DEMs you have are all in the same coordinate system/projection/units/cell size/etc.  If not, make sure you get all the rasters into identical formats before you start, it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Hi Kevin n Streppy, I had make sure that in my case the two DEM are identical formats. However, do you know why the resulted DEM has range value of 0 to 255? (Both the two source DEM have range 0 to more than 2000 m). Thanks before

Comment: As a newbie to this tool, I had to poke around the Toolbox before finding the command, as the full path was cut off in the screenshot: ArcToolbox\Data Management Tools\Raster\Raster Dataset\Mosaic to New Raster

Answer (score 6):

The range value issue of 0 to 255 that you are having is because of the pixel type being set to 8_BIT. TO have higher numbers set a higher bit value.

From ArcMap Tool Help

> 1_BIT —A 1-bit unsigned integer. The values can be 0 or 1.
>
> 2_BIT —A 2-bit unsigned integer. The values supported can be from 0 to
>   3.
>
> 4_BIT —A 4-bit unsigned integer. The values supported can be from 0 to
>   15.
>
> 8_BIT_UNSIGNED —An unsigned 8-bit data type. The values supported can
>   be from 0 to 255.
>
> 8_BIT_SIGNED —A signed 8-bit data type. The values supported can be
>   from -128 to 127.
>
> 16_BIT_UNSIGNED —A 16-bit unsigned data type. The values can range
>   from 0 to 65,535.
>
> 16_BIT_SIGNED —A 16-bit signed data type. The values can range from
>   -32,768 to 32,767.
>
> 32_BIT_UNSIGNED —A 32-bit unsigned data type. The values can range
>   from 0 to 4,294,967,295.
>
> 32_BIT_SIGNED —A 32-bit signed data type. The values can range from
>   -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
>
> 32_BIT_FLOAT —A 32-bit data type supporting decimals.
>
> 64_BIT —A 64-bit data type supporting decimals.